# finfo class not found after APC installation

Tags: php, apache, apc, fileinfo

I asked my hosting company to install APC to speed up my site, but I'm getting this problem now:

```
Fatal error:  Class 'finfo' not found in /home/mydomain/public_html/printshop/upload_1-img.php on line 30
```

Line 30 is:

```
$file_info = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
```

In `upload_1-img.php` I'm using fileinfo to get the mime type of uploaded images. This was working perfectly successfully for MONTHS, until I just got APC installed yesterday.

This is the first time I'm using APC, I don't have much experience. These are my runtime settings:

```
apc.cache_by_default    1
apc.canonicalize    1
apc.coredump_unmap  0
apc.enable_cli  0
apc.enabled 1
apc.file_md5    0
apc.file_update_protection  2
apc.filters 
apc.gc_ttl  3600
apc.include_once_override   0
apc.lazy_classes    0
apc.lazy_functions  0
apc.max_file_size   1M
apc.mmap_file_mask  /tmp/apc.GGV9Km
apc.num_files_hint  1000
apc.preload_path    
apc.report_autofilter   0
apc.rfc1867 1
apc.rfc1867_freq    0
apc.rfc1867_name    APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
apc.rfc1867_prefix  upload_
apc.rfc1867_ttl 3600
apc.serializer  default
apc.shm_segments    1
apc.shm_size    128M
apc.shm_strings_buffer  4M
apc.slam_defense    1
apc.stat    1
apc.stat_ctime  0
apc.ttl 1800
apc.use_request_time    1
apc.user_entries_hint   4096
apc.user_ttl    1800
apc.write_lock  1
```

Comment: `fileinfo` is a `PECL` extension, was it enabled after adding `APC`?

Comment: PECL must have been enabled before adding APC because it was working before the APC installation, is there a setting to let it run under APC?

Comment: But it could also be disabled after installing APC, even if it was enabled before. Or Your whole php installation could be recompiled to some older/newer version to make it possible to use APC, and not all other extensions were enabled. There is no setting in APC to make it work, nor there is one to prevent it from running, so the only possibility I see is disabled fileinfo extension.

Comment: I checked the "configure command" in phpinfo(), and this is the beginning: 
`'./configure' '--disable-fileinfo' '--disable-posix' '--enable-bcmath' '--enable-calendar' '--enable-exif' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--enable-libxml' '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-pdo=shared' '--enable-soap' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-sqlite-utf8' '--enable-zip' ` ... and it goes on. The beginning does seem to be disabling fileinfo. how can I re-enable it?

Comment: ask your hosting company to enable it, either by recompiling whole php or just compiling shared extension and enabling it in `php.ini`